# Scroll the page when a canvas is touch dragged

Tags: javascript, mobile, canvas

I have an HTML5 canvas that users interact with by clicking (or tapping).

```
$(function() {
  var canvas = $('#annotations');
  canvas[0].addEventListener('mousedown', clickCanvas);
  canvas[0].addEventListener('touchstart', clickCanvas);
});

function clickCanvas(e) {
  markLocation(e);
  drawCanvas();
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

This works as expected. However, on mobile devices if you tap and drag this registers a click at the point where the tap started (this makes sense because it's hooked up to `touchstart`). The page does not scroll as it normally does when you touch-drag outside the canvas.

When dragging, I would like the tap to be ignored **and the whole page scrolled instead**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by:

- Removing `e.preventDefault();`
- Hooking up `canvas[0].onselectstart = function () { return false; }` to prevent text being selected when the canvas is double-clicked (this was what `e.preventDefault()` did in the first place)
- Replacing `touchstart` with `touchend`